# iPhone CorePlot: Chart with user Touch Event

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

I am now using Core-plot to develop application.
I am looking for some touch event for user touch one point of the chart,
then it show up the price.

When i take a look of the CorePlot website,
It has a application show what i need
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/AppsUsingCorePlot

[image]

I really want to do this function by Core-plot, 
i am now using CorePlot 0.4
i want to do the following function
[image]

[image]

I really want to have a touch event which can show the specify price of the point user touch.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

CorePlot provides a lot of ways to detect user touches:

For plots:

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
-(void)pieChart:(CPPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

For plot space:

```
@protocol CPPlotSpaceDelegate <NSObject>
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

Answer (score 6):

The Mac CPTTestApp example program included with Core Plot shows how to do exactly what you describe. Look at the *Point Selection Demo* under the View menu.

Answer (score 1):

use gesture recolonization for this it work fine.in first tap u show price and second hide.