# iOS library that supports movable point (line chart)

Tags: ios, frameworks, charts, core-plot

I'm new to iOS and chart related kinda stuff. I wanted to create a line chart for iOS which allows user to customize the points as they want. For example user can drag the points on Y Axis.

I found out there is an open source library Core-Plot which might able to create line chart similar to the example link. But I'm not really sure about it and I cant find any clear explanation and sample project. So I wanted to ask here that, is it possible to use Core-Plot for such task and if it's possible please do provide any sample function/code that can be used for this purpose.

Please do suggests if there is any library (commercial or open source) that can perform such task. 
I looked up and found (Commercial) ShinobiChart and Acollada iOS Charting but not sure whether can perform such task yet.

Comment: For example it will be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/7UsbM/7/

Comment: you could use a UIWebView and your example?

Comment: @j_mcnally That might work, but currently I'm exploring other options to check whether other framework can do similar task.

Comment: SwiftCharts https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts can be used for this. It doesn't support this functionality out of the box but you can generate custom views with it, where you can attach the dragging functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope below links will help you.

Core-Plot sample codes:

http://tech.pro/tutorial/939/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

[piechart](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1)

http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/

http://www.gilthonwe.com/2012/06/09/stacked-bar-chart-coreplot-ios/

Comment: +1 Those were good and helpful tutorial to start with Core-Plot. But currently I kinda need information regarding Line Chart with Movable Points. Have you come across anything like that?

Comment: [refer this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7833210/966351)

Comment: The referred link contain information of detecting user touch on screen, how do I approach to drag points function from there?

Comment: -(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
 NSLog(@"point.x=%lf,point.y=%lf",point.x,point.y);
 return YES;
} - this will handle drag points... [http://blog.essencework.com/post/9413676170/put-some-touch-interactive-to-coreplot-on-ipad-part-2](http://blog.essencework.com/post/9413676170/put-some-touch-interactive-to-coreplot-on-ipad-part-2)

Comment: I tried that project and it doesn't allow to drag the points on Y axis.